# volley.ParseError - java.lang.String cannot be converted

Tags: android, json, volley

Olá,

Estou enviando **POST** para um arquivo **PHP** utilizando a biblioteca **Volley**. Tudo ocorre bem até a aplicação tentar mostrar a resposta ao usuário. No arquivo **PHP** uso o comando ***echo 'usuario_criado';***. A aplicação apresenta o seguinte erro:

**Error: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value usuario_criado of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject**

Peço desculpas por não ser o logcat, mas é que estou testando a aplicação em um celular real.

Aqui está o código que utilizo para enviar o **POST**.

```
    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    map.put("nickname", userName);
    request = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,
            url,
            new JSONObject(map),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response){
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, "Resposta: " + response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, "Erro: " + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );
    queue.add(request);
```

Comment: Voce ja verificou se esta recebendo um valor no formato JSON? veja este post => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30196601/volley-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject

Comment: Não estou passando em formato Json, amigo, apenas dou um echo no texto. Mas já tentei imprimir no formato json, tentei também adicionar o header como application/json. Foram duas possíveis soluções que encontrei pela internet, mas nenhuma delas ajudou.

Comment: estava procurando aqui e nao é aconselhavel usar um JsonObjectRequest para receber um string

Comment: Como deveria ser feito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou explicar o erro: isso ocorre porque você não estar recebendo a resposta do servidor em formato JSON e sim um String escrita **"usuario_criado"** e por isso ocorre o erro  **com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value usuario_criado of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject** 
Possíveis Soluções:
1- Você programar seu servidor para responder um JSON exemplo

```
echo '{"mensagem": "usuario_criado"}';
```

2- Você usar o StringRequest do volley segue o Doc [Volley](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/volley/simple.html)